# Scrollable ul list up and down from links with classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to scroll a news article list up and down depending on which buttons is clicked

I wanted to adapt this way of animating if possible:

```
function smoothAdd(id, text)
{
    var el = $('#scroller' + id);

    var h = el.height();

    el.css({
        height:   h,
        overflow: 'hidden'
    });

    var ulPaddingTop = parseInt(el.css('padding-top'));
    var ulPaddingBottom = parseInt(el.css('padding-bottom'));

    el.prepend('<li>' + text + '</li>');

    var first = $('li:first', el);
    var last  = $('li:last',  el);

    var foh = first.outerHeight();

    var heightDiff = foh - last.outerHeight();

    var oldMarginTop = first.css('margin-top');

    first.css({
        marginTop: 0 - foh,
        position:  'relative',
        top:       0 - ulPaddingTop
    });

    last.css('position', 'relative');

    el.animate({ height: h + heightDiff }, 1500)

    first.animate({ top: 0 }, 250, function() {
        first.animate({ marginTop: oldMarginTop }, 1000, function() {
            last.animate({ top: ulPaddingBottom }, 250, function() {
                last.remove();

                el.css({
                    height:   'auto',
                    overflow: 'visible'
                });
            });
        });
    });
}

  $('.scrollUp').click(function() {
      smoothAdd('scrollUp', 'A new item');
  });
```

Example here: http://www.fiveminuteargument.com/blog/scrolling-list

My HTML looks like this:

```
  <ul id="scroller">
      <li class="current"><span>/</span><a href="#article1">News Article Title</a></li>
      <li><span>/</span><a href="#article2">News Article Title 2</a></li>
      <li><span>/</span><a href="#article3">News Article Title 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="btnWrap"><p><a href="#arrow" class="scrollUp">Scroll Up</a>
  <a href="#arrow" class="scrollDown">Scroll Up</a></p></div>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Basically maintain the animation style but keep it as a defined UL as per a normal carousel.

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here : http://jsfiddle.net/sDedY/13/

I've written form scratch. as you notice I've added css directly in a css file, it's better than adding css via jquery, especially for future mainenance/ decorateion etc.., but I havent spent much time for different caluclations. This is a blueprint I guess, you can modify and make it much better, like make top and bottom combined to make the function small or things like that, i jsut dont have time anymore ... so again : redo the calculations based on css yourself and modify it !

**EDIT :** regarding variable height, you need to keep in mind that I haven't finalised the whole function. next step in coding this function would be auto-calculation of margin-top and top rather than manually entering them, which is pretty easy. all that's needed is to pass a variable to get the position and dimensions of li elements and then pass them to our code.

Comment: I got a final exam tomorrow(it's a medicine exam, if we fail we have to repeat the whole year !!!) but I found your problem interesting enough to spend 3 hours on it :D

Comment: p.s. for others, feel free to use my code, BUT if you mention my alias (hakim-sina) I'd really appreciate it ><

Comment: Your solution does not support items of variable height, as stated by the article that Andy posted

Comment: well, if you read my post, I did mention that I worked on it pretty quickly and didn't fully develop the whole thing (and Im sure Andy doesnt want nor he should want that) ... what I have provided is the basic framework for such a task and for example for variable height, you only need to add one more variable to the code. please don't depriciate my hard work, and make more genuine criticsm

Comment: I am not depreciating your hard work in any way. I just made a valid comment, sorry if you misunderstood it.

Answer (score 0):

I've change a few lines of your code:

`var el = $('#scroller' + id);` to `var el = $('#' + id);`

and

`smoothAdd('scrollUp', 'A new item');` to `smoothAdd('scroller', 'A new item');`

see http://jsfiddle.net/nCWAP/

Comment: What if we just had a full list of li then instead of adding the text we just hide or display them in order with the same effect.  When it reaches to the top of the list it just stops?

Comment: well in that case you might want to look at some plugins. for example: http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/

Comment: Thanks but i wanted to keep the same effect of it dropping off if possible

Answer (score 0):

I made a slightly simpler solution. Check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ruisoftware/kSQvD/9/)

You don't need to mess with `absolute` or `relative` position neither with `top`. The list has `height` as `auto` so it grows/shrinks according to the height of their `li` elements

**EDIT**
Now the height is automatically adjusted to show all items.

Also supports `li` elements of any height.

Comment: yeah that's an obvious option for such things, but if you noticed the question, Andy wants the effect as well ...

Comment: as I mentioned before, your code is definitly the fastet way of achieving a simpler version of what andy wants, but if you notice the source code that andy has posted, that's not the effect that you have created ... look at my code as well

Comment: @hakim-sina please check my new code now, I have changed to a smoother version